# How would a change in mean of the lognormal distribution (keeping variance constant) change the distribution?

Tags: statistics

For normal distribution, a change in mean of the distribution will just lead to horizontal shift of the PDF if it is graphed.

I am wondering if this is also the case for lognormal distribution. (i.e. will the shape of the lognormal distribution graph be affected by the mean of the distribution?)

Thanks for answering my question!

Comment: By changing the mean do you mean changing the parameter $\mu$ and leaving $\sigma$ the same or changing $E(X)$ and maintaining $Var(X)$ constant somehow?